# how to design REST API when resources have multiple states

Tags: rest, http

I am going to design REST API for incident reporting in my web application. An incident has three states. i.e. investigation incident,resolved and postmortem. I use three database tables for each state.I want to design rest api for creating new incident to database. Here new incident means that incident in investigation state.

I have tried two approaches for designing rest api. In first approach I consider three states as sub resources.

```
POST - /incident/investigation
POST - /incident/resolved
POST - /incident/postmortem
```

In second approach, I think to pass incident state in http response of POST method.

```
POST-/incident
```

What is the best way to design REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REST API should identify the resource, so you'd have something like `/incident/123` to denote incident number 123. And `/incident/123/status` would be the current status of that particular incident.

As each incident is in exclusively one state, you don't have the "multiple states" problem.

Comment: Is status a path parameter? (I want to post different types of json in three states.)

Comment: IMO yes. I think of "incidents" as structured data, where the path to the whole is a prefix for the paths to parts of the data.

Comment: If I use  /incident/123/{status} then I have to use multiple post requests with different application/json.

Comment: True. That's exactly how I implemented it. `/foo` refers to the whole JSON object, and `/foo/bar` just to the `bar` sub-object. I don't get the `{}` in `{status}`, I literally mean `/incident/{incidentnumber}/status`. That would be the just the `status` subkey of the whole `/incident/{incidentnumber}`